# Value cannot be null. Deserialize Object Json

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having issues deserializing this json string to a c# object.  I have tried numerous different configuration of the model and i have tried to serialize the code and let the mvc value providers to do this, but i can't get it to work.....  So I am sending this JSON string to my controller and then putting it into an object and then creating the correct object to throw it in my database.

```
[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value]
   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings) +162
   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings) +66
   InSight.Controllers.QuestionController.CreateSimpleQuestion(String json) +25
```

This is the string before i send it to my controller:

```
var data = JSON.stringify({
            QuestionTitle: title,
            Keywords: key,
            Description: desc,
            Comments: comments,
            QuestionType: type,
            choices: {
                DisplayText: text,
                OrderNumber: order,
                is_correct:is_correct
            }
        });
```

This is the controller method:

```
public ActionResult CreateSimpleQuestion(string json)
    {
        SimpleQuestion temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SimpleQuestion>(json);
        Question question = new Question();
        question.QuestionTitle = temp.QuestionTitle;
        question.QuestionType = temp.QuestionType;
        question.Keywords = temp.Keywords;
        question.is_counted = true;
        question.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
        question.Comments = temp.Comments;
        question.QuestionType = "Simple";
        db.Questions.Add(question);

        db.QuestionChoices.Add(temp.choices.First());
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

and this is the model:

```
public class SimpleQuestion
    {
            public int QuestionId { get; set; }

            public string QuestionTitle { get; set; }

            public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

            public string QuestionType { get; set; }

            public string Keywords { get; set; }

            public bool is_counted { get; set; }

            public string Description { get; set; }

            public string Comments { get; set; }

        public List<QuestionChoices> choices { get; set; }
    }
```

finally, this is the actual string of data that is getting passed:

```
{"QuestionTitle":"This is the Question Title",
"Keywords":"Blue pony, sharks",
"Description":"This is the description field.",
"Comments":"No comment has been left.",
"choices":{
    "DisplayText":"Will it rain tomorrow?",
    "OrderNumber":"1","is_correct":false
  }
}
```

**Solution**
Change the JS where `data` was defined to the following:

```
            var data = {
            "QuestionTitle": title,
            "Keywords": key,
            "Description": desc,
            "Comments": comments,
            "QuestionType": type,
            "choices": {
                "DisplayText": text,
                "OrderNumber": order,
                "is_correct":false
            }
        };
```

Comment: In this JSON `choices` is a **single object**, whereas in your C# object it is a **list of objects**. A list of objects in JSON would be: `"choices": [ { obj1 }, { obj2 } ]`

Comment: How would I fix the stringify function to show that?  I think this is the actual issue for why the model binder isn't working right.

Comment: See my answer for this. Your JavaScript is already wrong, where choices is a single object too (instead of an array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The real solution for your problem is to use MVC's model binding feature**. Change your method parameter type to your class and MVC will bind the JSON value to it.

```
public ActionResult Create(SimpleQuestion model)
{
  // use model now
  // TO DO :Save and redirect
}
```

Make sure you are specifying the `contentType` property value as "***application/json***" in your ajax call.

Also you do not need to call stringify if it is a valid JSOn. The below code will work fine

```
$(function () {
    var data = {
        "QuestionTitle": "This is the Question Title",
        "Keywords": "Blue pony, sharks",
        "Description": "This is the description field.",
        "Comments": "No comment has been left.",
        "choices": {
            "DisplayText": "Will it rain tomorrow?",
            "OrderNumber": "1",
            "is_correct": false
        }
    };      
    $.post("@Url.Action("Create","Home")", data, null, 'application/json');

});
```

[image]

Comment: I was having a lot of issues with the model binding. I will attempt it again though. The code would look a lot cleaner.

Comment: error with initializing choices: `'...choices' is a 'property' but is being used like a 'type'`.

Comment: is that your property name >

Comment: Also make sure you mention `contentType` property when making the ajax call to specify what content type are you sending

Comment: `$.post('/Question/CreateSimpleQuestion/', data, null, 'application/json');`

Comment: There is no need to initialize the list - JSON.net will take care of that.

Comment: It's making the call to the controller without an issue.  Taking out that stringify stuff is what did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is - as so often when it comes to JSON - a mismatch between the JSON and your data structure.

In your data structure you have this: A list of QuestionChoices.

```
public List<QuestionChoices> choices { get; set; }
```

In your JSON you send this: A **single** object.

```
        choices: {
            DisplayText: text,
            OrderNumber: order,
            is_correct:is_correct
        }
```

Please keep in mind that in JSON an array (or a list) is described with **[]**. So the correct JSON would be this:

```
        choices: [{
            DisplayText: text,
            OrderNumber: order,
            is_correct:is_correct
        }]
```

Multiple choices would be seperated within the [] by a comma.

The problem originates in your JavaScript code already, where you define `choices` to be a single object - not an array containing a single object. Fix that, and your problem should disappear.